# IBM MQIPT Nodejs Support

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

Please let me know if it is possible to send messages to IBM MQ via MQIPT (Internet pass through) in nodejs. I checked the documentation of the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqlight and did not find any option to specify details like queue manager name, channel name etc, which I think is required to connect to MQ. The use case is to push message to MQ from lambda deployed in AWS cloud.

Answer (score 1):

MQ IPT only understands the MQ protocol, coming from an MQ client. Not the MQ Light (AMQP) protocol.

So for a NodeJS program, you can either use the MQ Light API with a different proxy mechanism in the DMZ, or use the MQ NodeJS package ('npm install ibmmq', and which prereqs the MQ C client library) and which could go through MQ IPT.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use ibmmq and windows-build-tools in windows and was able to run standalone node program. Please let me know what will be the required libraries to be installed in unix/linux machines